# A Paragraph Merger with Removing Overlapped Duplicated Lines in C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented, strings, classes, stream

I am trying to make a paragraph merger that takes multiple paragraphs and output a concatenated result with removing the duplicated overlapped lines due to redundancy. Each input paragraph is with the follows specifications.

- The leading/trailing spaces in each line have been removed.
- No empty line.

The output merged paragraph follows the rules as below.

- Paragraph input to `Update` method is concatenated after the previous input.
- If the line(s) from the start of the paragraph input to `Update` method is / are sequenced same (overlapped) as the end of the previous input, just keep single copy of the sequenced duplicated lines.
- The definition of duplicated lines here:

  - The content in two line should be totally the same, no “partial overlapping” cases need to be considered.
  - The content sequence in two blocks of lines should be totally the same.

**Example Input and Output**

Besides the rules, here's a use case.

- **Inputs**

  Input paragraph 1 example:

  ```
  Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.
  It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.
  We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.
  We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how:
  Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
  This site is all about getting answers.
  It's not a discussion forum.
  There's no chit-chat.
  ```

  Input paragraph 2 example:

  ```
  We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how:
  Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
  This site is all about getting answers.
  It's not a discussion forum.
  There's no chit-chat.
  Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.
  The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.
  The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".
  Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.
  Get answers to practical, detailed questions
  Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced.
  Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.
  ```
- **Expected Output**

  [image]

  The two block of text are the same, so keep single overlapped part after merging.

  [image]

  ```
  Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.
  It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.
  We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.
  We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how:
  Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
  This site is all about getting answers.
  It's not a discussion forum.
  There's no chit-chat.
  Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.
  The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.
  The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".
  Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.
  Get answers to practical, detailed questions
  Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced.
  Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.
  ```

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation is as below.

```
[Serializable]
class ParagraphMerger
{
    private List<string> paragraphContents;

    public ParagraphMerger(List<string> input)
    {
        this.paragraphContents = input;
    }

    public ParagraphMerger(string[] input)
    {
        this.paragraphContents = input.ToList();
    }

    public ParagraphMerger Update(List<string> input)
    {
        return Update(input.ToArray());
    }

    public ParagraphMerger Update(string[] input)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        foreach (var element in input)
        {
            if (((!IsStringExist(paragraphContents, element)) || flag) && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element)))
            {
                paragraphContents.Add(element);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var element in this.paragraphContents)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(element);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private bool IsStringExist(List<string> strings, string target)
    {
        if (strings is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (target is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        foreach (var element in strings)
        {
            if (element.Equals(target))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

The test case here use `ParagraphMerger` class with `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText`. The content of "paragraph1.txt" is as "Input paragraph 1" above and "paragraph2.txt" is as "Input paragraph 2" above.

```
var paragraph1 = File.ReadAllText("paragraph1.txt").Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var paragraph2 = File.ReadAllText("paragraph2.txt").Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

ParagraphMerger paragraphMerger = new ParagraphMerger(paragraph1);
paragraphMerger.Update(paragraph2);

File.WriteAllText("output.txt", paragraphMerger.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(paragraphMerger.ToString());
```

All suggestions are welcome. If there is any issue about:

- Data processing performance
- The naming and readability
- Potential drawbacks of the implemented methods

, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Readonly Field

As you assign the field only once in constructor, you may make it `readonly`. It makes the compiler able to apply more good optimisations to it.

#### List constructor

You store a reference to the list passed by the argument, store the copy instead because when you modifying passed list, you'll change the source list. It can cause an unexpected behavior for the external code. `input.ToList()` makes a copy of the collection even if it's already a List.

#### IEnumerable

You made the class to accept both arrays a lists. You may use `IEnumerable<string>` instead that's compartible with both.

#### IsStringExist()

Consider to use [List.Contains(T)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `Equals` in loop.

`strings is null` can be moved to `return` statement

#### Update()

Name can be improved e.g. `AppendLines()` as based on what the method do.

In multiple conditions per logical expression the fastest can be checked first. Move `flag` to the first place, then `IsStringExist()` will not be called if `flag` is `true`. But `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element)` can moved in front of all to remove `null` argument check from `IsStringExist()` method. An then `IsStringExist()` will be optimized to single `List.Contains()` call and optimized out as redundant.

#### Small thigs

As option `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element)` can be replaced with `element?.Trim().Length > 0` but it will change nothing.

`ToString()` can be made with simple `return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, paragraphContents)`. `string.Join` uses `StringBuilder` under the hood too. The behavior difference is no CRLF at the end of the output.

```cs
[Serializable]
class ParagraphMerger
{
    private readonly List<string> paragraphContents;

    public ParagraphMerger(IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        paragraphContents = input.ToList();
    }

    public ParagraphMerger AppendLines(IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        foreach (var element in input)
        {
            if (element?.Trim().Length > 0 && (flag || !paragraphContents.Contains(element)))
            {
                paragraphContents.Add(element);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, paragraphContents);
    }
}
```

And finally usage example

```cs
var paragraph1 = File.ReadAllLines("paragraph1.txt"); // File class have a lot of interesting methods, check the docs
var paragraph2 = File.ReadAllLines("paragraph2.txt");

ParagraphMerger paragraphMerger = new ParagraphMerger(paragraph1);
paragraphMerger.AppendLines(paragraph2);

string text = paragraphMerger.ToString(); // call ToString() once and reuse
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", text);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: I upvoted despite my having strong objections to the suggestion of using `element?.Trim().Length > 0` instead of `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element)`.

Comment: @RickDavin `but it will change nothing` That is just a syntax preference. We are not talking about performance or memory. If we are, `null` checking is redundant here because regarding to the usage example the `elemant` can't be `null`. Also in case of performance sensitivity `Span<char>` is the best to use. Also `TrimStart()` is faster than `Trim()`, bulk operations can be vectorised/intrinsified, etc. And i'm not sure if removing empty lines is useful here. In plain text i can split paragraphs with empty lines, and removing it isn't a thing to do. But OP decided to do that, I followed.